# How does the contest for naming ExoMars work?

Tags: mars, rovers, esa

ESA is holding a contest to collect suggestions for a proper name for what is currently referred to as the [ExoMars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExoMars_(rover)) rover mission to Mars ([mission page](http://exploration.esa.int/mars/48088-mission-overview/)).

Apparently, Rovy McRoverface and Marsy McMarsface has been fairly well excluded by the ESA after Boaty McBoatface lost out to [RRS Sir David Attenborough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRS_Sir_David_Attenborough), although [Boaty McBoatface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaty_McBoatface) and [Boomy McBoomface](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/13740/6031) have in fact been used elsewhere.

How does the contest work? Can anyone enter a suggested name? Will most or all of the suggestions be posted and voted on, or will only the winner and a few runners-up be announced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [BBC article about the announcement](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/amp/science-environment-44889596):

> All ideas will be put before an expert panel and it is they who will make the final choice.

the competition website is [here](https://events.airbus.com/ereg/index.php?eventid=200179103&).

From the [terms and conditions](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/exomars-rover-naming-competition-terms-and-conditions) of the contest:

> The UK Space Agency will appoint a judging panel. That panel will select a winning name from **all** the names submitted. The decision of the panel of judges (acting reasonably) will be final. If more than ten entrants submit the same winning name, 10 entrants will be selected at random from those with the winning name.
> As part of their decision, the panel will consider whether the name is acceptable to all ESA Member States.
> A list of names of the judges can be viewed on the UK Space Agency website from the Closing Date for a period of 30 days.
>
> You agree that the Promoter may, but is not required to, make your entry available on the UK Space Agency Website and any other media,